# ordenar array por data

Tags: php, lógica

criei uma função que ela faz o selet no banco de dados e retorna os dados em array e agora estou querendo ordenar a resposta dela por data exemplo

Resposta retornada da função

```
    Array ( [dados-0] => Array ( [valor-0] => 300 [date-0] => 26/2/2019 )
        [dados-1] => Array ( [valor-1] => 150 [date-1] => 26/2/2019 ) 
        [dados-2] => Array ( [valor-2] => 150 [date-2] => 26/3/2019 ) 
        [dados-3] => Array ( [valor-3] => 5000 [date-3] => 9/3/2019 ) 
        [dados-4] => Array ( [valor-4] => 300 [date-4] => 10/3/2019 ) 
      )
```

E assim por diante eu quero ordenar da ordem mas antiga para mais velha ficando assim:

```
 Array ( [dados-0] => Array ( [valor-0] => 300 [date-0] => 26/2/2019 )
    [dados-1] => Array ( [valor-1] => 150 [date-1] => 26/2/2019 )
    [dados-3] => Array ( [valor-3] => 5000 [date-3] => 9/3/2019 )  
    [dados-2] => Array ( [valor-2] => 150 [date-2] => 10/3/2019 )   
    [dados-4] => Array ( [valor-4] => 300 [date-4] => 26/3/2019 ) 
  )
```

Alguem consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu tive refazer a resposta.

Para fazer o que você precisa eu criei duas funções. Uma para alterar os valores das datas recursivamente. E a outra para pegar a primeira data encontrada no array para poder fazer a ordenação.

São estas funções:

```
    // função que aplica uma função passada por parâmetro em todos os elementos do array
    function array_map_recursive(callable $func, array $array){
        $res = [];
        foreach ($array as $k => $v)
            $res[$k] = is_array($v) ? array_map_recursive($func, $v) : $func(trim($v));
        return $res;
    }

    // função que recupera a primeira data encontrada em um array
    function getDataInArray(array $array){
        foreach($array as $val){
            if(is_array($val)) return getDataInArray($array);
            if(preg_match('/\d{2,4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}(?=$)/', $val)) return $val;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Depois eu utilizei as funções da seguinte forma (código comentado):

```
    // altera o array para ser ordenado ( formato será por exemplo 2015-02-30 )
    $new = array_map_recursive(function($v){
        // identifica se é uma data. Se for uma data retorna uma nova data com o formato americano.
        return preg_match('/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}(?=$)/', $v) ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $v))) : $v;
    }, $dados);

    // ordena o array preservando as chaves
    uasort($new, function($a,$b){
        return strcmp(getDataInArray($a), getDataInArray($b));
    });

    // altera o array para ser usado ( formato será por exemplo 30/02/2015 )
    $dados = array_map_recursive(function($v){
        // identifica se é uma data. Se for uma data retorna uma nova data com o formato brasileiro.
        return preg_match('/\d{2,4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}(?=$)/', $v) ? date("d/m/Y", strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $v))) : $v;
    }, $new);

    // exibe
    print_r($dados);
```

**[Exemplo do script no Ideone](https://ideone.com/b1yY4d)**

Comment: e se tiver mais dados tipo ele voltar dessa maneira." 
Array ( [dados-0] => Array ( [valor-0] => 300 [date-0] => 26/2/2019 ) [dados-1] => Array ( [valor-1] => 150 [date-1] => 26/2/2019 ) [dados-2] => Array ( [valor-2] => 150 [date-2] => 26/3/2019 ) [dados-3] => Array ( [valor-3] => 5000 [date-3] => 9/3/2019 ) [dados-4] => Array ( [valor-4] => 300 [date-4] => 10/3/2019 ) )"

Comment: cada dado tem uma array ai tenho q ordenar pela data q esta dentro da array

Comment: @CyberHacker o problema é que esse array ai é multidimensional! Diferente do array que você postou!

Comment: @CyberHacker como você quer o resultado desse array? Coloca na pergunta.

Comment: @CyberHacker amanhã eu crio uma solução. Hoje acho que não vou conseguir.

Comment: sim, pois achei q ele ia ordenar so por data e os outro iria inrelavar porem notei q n funcionou do cheito q queria ai coloquei em um array multidimensional oara ver se arrumava e estou quebrando a cabeça aqui

Comment: @CyberHacker fiz a edição pra você

Comment: nossa muito obrigado mesmo, agora irei ler e estudar seu codigo para entender melhor muito obrigado

Comment: @CyberHacker tranquilo meu querido!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer o SELECT te retornar ordenado como você quer, ao invés de ter que trabalhar isso no php. Para isso, no final do seu `SELECT` você precisa colocar: `ORDER BY nome_campo_data`. Por padrão o sql ordena em ordem crescente.

Comment: O ideal é fazer isso!

Comment: Sim eu pensei nisso porem ia ter q modificar varias partes da funçao q criei, pois ela n esta aceitando o orde by pois passa por uns procedimento antes de fazer a solicitação ao banco, por isso estou tentando achar uma meio que eu possa arrumar sem precisar usar o orde by, e tambem as datas estão separadas teria que criar um as para modificar e unir para depois dar o ordeby

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia utilizar a função `sort` do PHP se você tivesse suas datas no formato "Ano-Mês-Dia", ou então se suas datas fossem um timestamp.

Alias, essa é a forma que eu recomendaria gravar no seu banco de dados. O próprio BD poderia ordenar o resultado para você se estivesse gravado em um formato padrão, "Dia/Mês/Ano" provavelmente irá te dar mais dor de cabeça no futuro.

O que lhe resta é converter o formato das suas datas, organizá-las, e então converte-las de volta ao formato original.

```
$datas = [
    '29/02/2016',
    '30/02/2015',
    '27/02/2013',
    '28/02/2014',
];

// converte datas para timestamp
foreach ($datas as $data) {
    $timestamps[] = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $data));
}

// ordena 
sort($timestamps);

// converte timestamp para datas
foreach ($timestamps as $timestamp) {
    $data_ordenado[] = date('m/d/Y', $timestamp); 
}

// imprime o array
// 02/27/2013, 02/28/2014, 03/02/2015, 02/29/2016
var_dump($data_ordenado);
```